# transfer variables from a main script to a different shell started from the first script

Tags: bash, variables

Ok so I'm sorry if this is a no-brainer, if it is unclear, or if it is impossible but here is my code, I am trying to get the /usr/bin/expect line of code to inherit/get variables from the main script. Its not working because it was started with a different shell (I think) and so it's not loading the variables in. This is my first post so if I am doing anything wrong please kindly correct me ;)

Thanks in advance,
--A\\/

```
#!/bin/bash

red="\x1b[0;31m"
nc="\x1b[0m"


####### commented out till scipt is finished
# if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
# echo -e "${red}[!]${nc} | script must be run as root"
# exit
# fi

read -p '[?] | ip address of device: ' ip
read -p '[?] | nickname to set for this config: ' name
read -p '[?] | username to generate keys for: ' usr
read -p '[?] | password for that user: ' pw


export $usr
export $pw
export $ip
export $name


/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ssh $usr@$ip; expect"(yes/no)? "; send "yes\r"; expect "Password:"; send "$pw"; interact'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to 1. export them correctly, and 2. use `$env(foo)` to refer to them:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="World"
export var   # No $
expect -c 'spawn echo Hello $env(var); interact'
```

Comment: Is there a way to get variables from the expect script and pull them into the bash script?

Comment: Variables are only inherited, not transferred. You would have to write them to stdout or a file, then capture the output or read the file.

Comment: ok thanks you guys all of that helped a lot